# Empty Datapoints set while fetching CloudWatch metrics using the AWS Java SDK?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, amazon-web-services

I have Spring web application, and I am trying to fetch information about EC-2 usage. Here is my code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
public class AdminIndexController {

    @Autowired
    private StatsService statsService;

    private final String awsAccessKey = "";
    private final String awsSecretKey = "";
    private final String instanceId = "";

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/index", "/index/" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = statsService.getEventNumbersCount();
        model.addAllAttributes(statsService.getEventNumbersCount());
        final AmazonCloudWatchClient client = client(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
        final GetMetricStatisticsRequest awsRequest = request(instanceId, "CPUUtilization");
        final GetMetricStatisticsResult result = result(client, awsRequest);
        toStdOut(result, instanceId);
        return "index";
    }

    private AmazonCloudWatchClient client(final String awsAccessKey, final String awsSecretKey) {
        final AmazonCloudWatchClient client = new AmazonCloudWatchClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey));
        client.setEndpoint("http://monitoring.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com");
        return client;
    }

    private GetMetricStatisticsRequest request(final String instanceId, String metricName) {
        final long twentyFourHrs = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
        final int oneHour = 60 * 60;
        return new GetMetricStatisticsRequest().withStartTime(new Date(new Date().getTime() - twentyFourHrs)).withNamespace("AWS/EC2").withPeriod(oneHour)
                .withDimensions(new Dimension().withName("InstanceId").withValue(instanceId)).withMetricName(metricName).withStatistics("Average", "Maximum")
                .withEndTime(new Date());
    }

    private GetMetricStatisticsResult result(final AmazonCloudWatchClient client, final GetMetricStatisticsRequest awsRequest) {
        return client.getMetricStatistics(awsRequest);
    }

    private void toStdOut(final GetMetricStatisticsResult result, final String instanceId) {
        System.out.println(result); // outputs empty result: {Label:
                                    // CPUUtilization,Datapoints: []}
        System.out.println(result.getDatapoints().size() + "SIZE!!!");
        for (final Datapoint dataPoint : result.getDatapoints()) {
            System.out.println("!!!!");
            System.out.printf("%s instance's average CPU utilization : %s%n", instanceId, dataPoint.getAverage());
            System.out.printf("%s instance's max CPU utilization : %s%n", instanceId, dataPoint.getMaximum());
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is, that my datapoints set is empty, even there is no error. I looked into the AWS management console, and statistics are available for my instance.

Do you know what might cause this behavior?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the I found the problem. It was obvious, I specified wrong region for an endpoint.
Code above works, I hope it will help somebody as an example.